# How to access the role of user in un-authenticated page in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

In my home page template `Index.html.twig` I have one navigation bar which i only want to show to Admin users if they are logged in , othwise not.

I tried this

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
       <div class="navigation">
       </div>
{% endif %}
```

But i get this error

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The
>   security context contains no authentication token. One possible reason
>   may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.

Now as this is home page i can't put it behind firewall. Is there any way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap in it an if block like so:

```
{% if app.user is not null %}
    {% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
        {# your code #}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: can i use two or more roles in is_granted() function like is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN','SUPER')